# Does JVM loads all used classes when loading a particular class?

Tags: java, classloader, jls

When JVM loads a class A, does it load all of the classes used within A?
And I'm wondering if import declarations are matter somehow to the loading process?

The link to JLS would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Import and class loading are unrelated.  The former just saves typing: it allows you to use the short class name rather than the fully-resolved class name in your code.

Classes are loaded by the [JVM](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html) when they're used for the first time.

Comment: Did I correctly understand the JLS, that it is implementation dependant what kind of resolution (static or lazy) would be applied?

Comment: I don't know what static resolution means; it's always been my understanding that classes are loaded when they are needed.  That says "lazy" to me.

Comment: I referred to the terms in the link you provided. =)

Answer (score 1):

`import` merely helps the programmer. When the class file is compiled the Qualified Name of the variables is stored in the .class file so the JVM knows what it needs to load.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#21410
section 2.17.1 "Virtual Machine Start-up"

Answer (score 0):

Importing a class is marker for the user and the compiler. Using import does not load classes. JVM loads class only when it referenced and if the classes are not required then the class does not load it on compile time or runtime.