# about import statement

Tags: java, import, classloader, heap-memory

I want to know where can I check how many classes have been loaded by the class loader.
I want to know, whether `import` statement in the class with `*` mark will load those many classes in the perm area of heap? OR only when we declare reference of the specific type 
then following two classes will be loaded?
Ex.

```
Map m = new HashMap(); //only these two classes loaded???
```

what if we write import statement like

```
java.util.*;
```

will class loader loads all classes under `java.util` package? 
Is there any class unloading process in java?

Comment: I think this answer should apply to your question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702423/does-jvm-loads-all-used-classes-when-loading-a-particular-class

Comment: The import statement has nothing whatsoever to do with class loading at runtime. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @EJP:- Yes. Thanks everybody. What about class unloading? is there any such process of class unloading? or do all class sits on 'perm' heap area till JVM shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the classes that are loaded at runtime try this:

```
java -verbose:class
```

You should have a look for Question [Is there a way to get which classes a ClassLoader has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432180/is-there-a-way-to-get-which-classes-a-classloader-has-loaded)

Answer (score 5):

No, import has nothing to do with class loading.  It is just syntax sugar.  The following two programs will produce exactly the same byte code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.prefs.*;

public class Foo
{
    private Map map = new HashMap ();
}
```

and

```
public class Foo
{
    private java.util.Map map = new java.util.HashMap ();
}
```

The time when class is loaded is up to JVM decision.  Java specification only guarantees that class will be loaded and initialized before first use.

For example one JVM may decide to load all classes directly or indirectly referred by main class recursively before application startup.  Such behavior could be handy for real-time applications that need to avoid non-deterministic pauses in program execution caused by class loading.  Another JVM may defer class loading until the class is actually used and unload class immediately after it is not used anymore.  This may be handy in embedded applications that are concerned by memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

`import`ed classes (or wildcards) are not actually loaded by the class loader. An import statement is merely an "alias" statement (or something like an "implicit prefix" statement in case you import wildcards).

Answer (score 1):

This tool [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) will help you.